# kohana 3.2 роутинг и изображения

Tags: роутинг, router, изображения, kohana

Здравствуйте! В корне коханы, вместе с папками application, system и modules создал папку под изображения img и в ней еще по папке для больших и уменьшенных. И если в адресе страницы нету / то они отображаются нормально, но когда появляются слеши / кохана почему-то сразу перестает находить изображения. На странице они выводятся как пустые квадратики, а при переходе по ссылке в исходном коде выдаётся ошибка: HTTP_Exception_404 [ 404 ]: Unable to find a route to match the URI: name/img/big/small_14303120101619.jpg Вывожу изображения при помощи img src  Не могу понять чего не хватает. Версия коханы 3.2

Comment: адрес в виде стоит правильный, проблема в том, что если в адресе страницы есть / то кохана начинает непонятно что. вот адрес страницы с фотками: http://localhost/site/user/photo . вот адрес изображения - http://localhost/site/img/images/1529111130421.jpg , а вот такая абра кадабра дописывается к нему при открытии изображения в браузере: http://localhost/site/user/img/images/1529111130421.jpg =\

Comment: все разобрался

Answer (score 1):

Проблема точно не в Кохане, а в том как ты обращаешься к фотографиям.
Все запросы переадресовываются к Кохане только если запрашиваемого файл не существует физически. Следовательно ты банально не правильно пишешь URL картинки.